# Using in-memory vector layer with QGIS processing / SEXTANTE

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, sextante, memory, qgis-processing

I'm trying to run the `qgis:clip` algorithm from console, but am getting an error when using an in-memory layer as the overlay parameter. Is this to be expected, or am I doing something wrong?

Code:

```
mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:4326", "temp_layer", "memory")
if not mem_layer.isValid(): raise Exception("Failed to create memory layer")            
mem_layer_provider = mem_layer.dataProvider()

clip_polygon = QgsFeature()
clip_polygon.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromRect( 
    QgsRectangle(
        self.output_layer.extent().xMinimum() + 10,
        self.output_layer.extent().yMinimum() + 10,
        self.output_layer.extent().xMaximum() - 10,
        self.output_layer.extent().yMaximum() - 10
    )
))
mem_layer_provider.addFeatures([clip_polygon])
mem_layer.updateExtents()

output = self.output_layer_path + "2"
processing.runalg("qgis:clip", layer, mem_layer, output) # Fails
```

In the code above, `self.output_layer` and `layer` are vector layer objects (QgsVectorLayer - proper ones, loaded from shapefiles on disk), `self.output_layer_path` is a python string object with a path.

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
"C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 150, in     
    execute self.processAlgorithm(progress)
File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\ftools\Clip.py", line 72, 
    in processAlgorithm index = utils.createSpatialIndex(layerB)
File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\ftools\FToolsUtils.py", 
    line 31, in createSpatialIndex features = QGisLayers.features(layer)
File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\QGisLayers.py", line 211, 
    in features return Features(layer)
File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\QGisLayers.py", line 218, 
    in __init__ self.iter = layer.getFeatures()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getFeatures'
```

If I change my processing call to the following, it runs without error:

```
processing.runalg("qgis:clip", layer, self.output_layer, output) # Runs fine
```

Also, if of any help, this is the failing algorithm as it is logged in processing_qgis.log:

```
processing.runalg("qgis:clip","C:/path/to/shapefile.shp|layerid=0|subset=CONTINENT = 
    'Europe'","Polygon?crs=epsg:4326","C:/path/to/output")
```

Comment: It's probably expected as the tool need to address a physical layer on the hard-drive. Just an idea, but why don't you temporarily try to save you layer into a temporary file (If you need a location `import tempfile` and `tempfile.gettempdir`). This is how qgis-processing works anyway

Comment: I will, if I have to.. Just easier and cleaner to work in memory for layers like these. If you are sure it's expected, post it as an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As it turns out, this works fine as long as you add the memory layer to the table of contents before using it. It seems the `dataobjects.getObjectFromUri` function in the QGIS source can't handle it otherwise.

So the following works very well:

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
processing.runalg("qgis:clip", layer, mem_layer, output)
```

Also see my [recent question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/76594) for how to use memory layers as output from processing functions (basically use `processing.runandload` instead of `processing.runalg`).