# How to load memory output from QGIS processing?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, sextante, memory, qgis-processing

Many processing algorithms have an option to save output as memory. If ran from toolbox, this works fine, because you can tick the "Open output file after running algorithm" box.

Looking at the source code for QGIS, the code for loading the memory layer seems to be defined in the function `Postprocessing.handleAlgorithmResults`. The function uses access to an `alg.outputs` list, and does the following:

```
for out in alg.outputs:
    progress.setPercentage(100 * i / float(len(alg.outputs)))
    if out.hidden or not out.open:
        continue
    if isinstance(out, (OutputRaster, OutputVector, OutputTable)):
        try:
            if out.value.startswith('memory:'):
                layer = out.memoryLayer                                # NOTE!!
                QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])   # NOTE!!
            else:
                # ...
```

When you run processing algorithms from the console, is there a way to load the layer without access to this object? I can run

```
processing.runalg("qgis:intersection", layer1, layer2, "memory:")
```

or even

```
processing.runalg("qgis:intersection", layer1, layer2, "memory:myLayerName")
```

I can however not find a way to grab the resulting output.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Aaaand I found it. Use `processing.runandload`, which loads the output layer into the table of contents after running the algorithm.

```
processing.runandload("qgis:intersection", layer1, layer2, "memory:myLayerName")
layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("memory:myLayerName")[0]
# Should do error checking as well, but this works!!
```

Comment: I am intrigued by the answer you found.  Do you know if there is a similar means of creating a memory layer - and being able to access it without implementing runandload?  I hope to do some post processing on the processing output before adding it to the canvas - and wondered if such is even possible...

Comment: I couldn't find one at the time, not to say that it's impossible... I guess you could load it and hide it, if that helps.

Comment: If you can't find layer name using `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("memory:myLayerName")[0]` try this: `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()`

Comment: @Katalpa you can try,  processing.runalg("qgis:intersection", layer1, layer2,'out.shp')

Answer (score 4):

it is the correct way, it's explained in the documentation 
http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/es/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html

the next code work with in memory all except the last that it is load

```
MDT=path/mdt.tif
drain=processing.runalg("grass:r.drain",MDT,"",(pun),False,False,False,"%f,%f,%f,%f"% (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),0,-1,0.00100,None)
vect=processing.runalg("grass:r.to.vect",drain['output'],0,False,"%f,%f,%f,%f"% (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),0,None)
bu=processing.runalg("qgis:fixeddistancebuffer",vect['output'],Metros_afecta,1,False,None)
buf=bu['OUTPUT']
bufe= QgsVectorLayer(buf,"area", "ogr")
#the last load the layer 
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([bufe])
```

the `processing.runalg` returns a dictionary in this case `bu['OUTPUT']`. `OUTPUT` IS THE KEY, and the value is a temp path. You can see the key with processeing.alghelp("name processing") as processing,alghelp("grass:r.drain")

return

```
processing.alghelp("grass:r.drain")
ALGORITHM: r.drain - Traces a flow through an elevation model on a raster map.
input <ParameterRaster>
coordinate <ParameterString>
vector_points <ParameterMultipleInput>
-c <ParameterBoolean>
-a <ParameterBoolean>
-n <ParameterBoolean>
GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER <ParameterExtent>
GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER <ParameterNumber>
GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER <ParameterNumber>
GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER <ParameterNumber>
output <OutputRaster>
```

in this case the key is **output** , take care with capital letters you must write in capital or without capital, in this case not capital.

Comment: Please avoid duplicate answers (http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/211730/8104), following Stack Exchange policy. More details: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227

Comment: This was the one that ultimately worked for me. The key info that was missing elsewhere was that you can pass the `output['OUTPUT']` path to `QgsVectorLayer` with a `provider_name` of `"ogr"`. This will read in the .shp path and create an in-memory layer. This approach doesn't add the layer to the registry, so it doesn't flash in the Layers Panel.

Comment: According to the manual page you reference, "The runalg method returns a dictionary with the output names (the ones shown in the algorithm description) as keys and the file paths of those outputs as values."  So this approach does not seem to use memory layers - all intermediate results will be stored in the file system.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will help you in your context (do you want to run your code as standalone or within QGIS after a processing algoritm finished?). 
If its the latter you could easily query loaded `QGsVector-` and `QGsRasterlayer` objects by looking into the QGIS MapLayer registry.

```
# General function to retrieve a layer with a given name
def getLayerByName( layerName ):
  layerMap = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()
  for name, layer in layerMap.iteritems():
    if layer.name() == layerName:
        if layer.isValid():
          return layer
        else:
          return None
```

In general all layers must have a source somewhere on the harddrive even if the result is just added after a processing-alg finishes its calculations. If you look into the layers metadata you can find the actual source of a layer (if its originating from processing its normally somewhere in a temporary folder)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think there already is a `getLayersByName` function for the map registry, but I want to run the algorithm from console myself, so this won't really help (the memory layer is never loaded into the registry, that's what I'm trying to do). But are you saying that there is no advantage to using a memory output compared to passing `None` and generating a temp file? Are you sure about that?

Comment: `None` is just passed if the layer can not be found in the registry. It doesn't create a tempfile and you need to check for it manually anyway. I use this function to query loaded layers within QGIS. Can't help you outside in the console.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I was talking about passing `None` to `processing.runalg` as the output parameter, which I believe creates a temp output file.

Comment: FYI: Just came across the QgsMapLayerRegistry function again, it's called `mapLayersByName`