# Performing in-memory difference operation between vector layers in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, vector-layer, in-memory

I've been working on a project using QGIS's Python API.  I need to create an in-memory layer that is defined as the difference between two polygonal vector layers, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to do this for a standalone script.

I've looked at the processing plugin, but it seems to require a file output.  I've seen that some people use the runandload() function ([How to load memory output from QGIS processing?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76594/how-to-load-memory-output-from-qgis-processing)), but this seems to be specifically for the QGIS GUI console, and I'm needing to generate the output layer in memory.

Comment: I'm not having difficulty creating an in-memory vector layer.  My issue is that I don't know how to access a difference operator that outputs to an in-memory vector layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably I don't completely understand your question.

Are you looking for something like this:

```py
diff = processing.runalg("qgis:difference", layer1, layer2, False, None) # you can use any name intead of diff
diff_res = processing.getObject(diff['OUTPUT']) # you can use any name intead of diff_res

# And then, for example:
for feature in diff_res.getFeatures():
    # some stuff
```

where `layer1` and `layer2` are your polygonal vector layers? In this way, you generate an output layer in memory without specifying a file output or loading it.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, actually.  I'll check to see how well it works for me.