# Difference between processing.runalg() and general.runalg()

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

In the discussion from a question I asked several days ago ([Using the processing framework in a PyQGIS standalone application](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221469/using-the-processing-framework-in-a-pyqgis-standalone-application)), someone suggested that I use general.runalg() instead of processing.runalg() for running QGIS algorithms.

I've now used both, and haven't noticed a difference in either performance or syntax between them.  I'm just wondering what sort of differences there are between these two methods, and which one I should be using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open a QGIS Python Console and run this:

```
import processing 
help( processing.runalg )
```

You will get:

```
Help on function runalg in module processing.tools.general:

runalg(algOrName, *args, **kwargs)
```

Which indicates us that by using `processing.runalg()`, you're actually  calling `general.runalg()`.

Note that if you want to call `general.runalg()` explicitly, you need to import the `general` module from `processing.tools`.

In summary, use whatever you want, just make sure you initialize Processing (`Processing.initialize()`) before calling `runalg()` if you're running a standalone PyQGIS script.