# Programmatically setting CRS for processing algorithm with a memory output layer

Tags: pyqgis, coordinate-system, qgis-processing

On QGIS 2.18.1, Python 2.7.12, Ubuntu 64 bit, I am struggling with setting a CRS for a memory output layer within an iteration over several years of observations for a protected area (PA) polygon layer ([UNEP-WCMC World PA database](https://www.protectedplanet.net/)). The solution I have found so far (see, e.g. [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76594/how-to-load-memory-output-from-qgis-processing)) builds upon generating a multipart vector layer for a sub-selection of PA per year as a memory layer in order to intersect with [GADM](http://gadm.org/) country polygons. This, however, requires a manual input of selecting the CRS for the memory layer. Is there a way of doing this automatically?

The code that requires solution:

```
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

# singlepart to multipart algorithm
processing.runandload('qgis:singlepartstomultipart', my_PA_vl, "my_field_of_country_ISO3", "memory:my_output_layer_name") # for this step I would like to set CRS for mem layer automatically
my_output_layer_name = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("Multipart")[0]
```

Setting the output layer to `None` - which should set the memory layer CRS to input layer CRS (?) - somehow does not generate any output.

Potentially, there might even be a better solution / approach for what I am intending...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output will have the same crs of your input layer. You will be obviously able to change the crs of the output layer, but only in a further step.

Probably I don't completely understand your question, however I think you essentially want to manage the output of the `'qgis:singlepartstomultipart'` algorithm for an intersection. If so, you need to choose a name for the current operation and to set your output to `None`. Then, you will able to handle your result for the next step:

```py
from qgis.core import *

# You can use any name instead of 'result'
result = processing.runalg('qgis:singlepartstomultipart', my_PA_vl, "my_field_of_country_ISO3", None) 

# You can use any name instead of 'my_res'
my_res = processing.getObject(result['OUTPUT']) 

# And then, for example:
intersection = processing.runalg("qgis:intersection", my_res, country_polygons ,False,None):
# where 'country_polygons' is the name of the layer you wish to intersect with 'my_res'
```

If you want to add your layer to the Layers panel, you may insert this in your preferred position:

```py
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(my_res)
```

I hope this will help you, otherwise I can edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks, you actually got what I wanted quite right. The `my_res = processing.getObject(result['OUTPUT'])` bit  yields `AttributeError: SinglePartsToMultiparts instance has no attribute '__getitem__'` !? Nevertheless, `all_PA = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("Multipart")[0]` did work, since setting the output directory to `None` did produce the desired output of a memory layer, such that this solved my problem.

Comment: I tested the code on sample data, and it worked for me... Are you sure that you properly load the `my_PA_vl` layer or that the `"my_field_of_country_ISO3"` field exists?

Comment: Yeah, the `result` object has successfully generated without requiring a manual CRS input. That solved my problem. I was referring to the second line, which did not work for me since `my_res = processing.getObject(result['OUTPUT'])` gives `AttributeError: SinglePartsToMultiparts instance has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: That's weird... However, I'm glad you solved your problem =)

Comment: Actually, you did ;D