# How to call a temporary layer from another python script in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I wrote several python scripts called by my main.py script.
In one of those scripts I create a vector layer by polygonizing a raster layer. As the layer is really heavy and as I don't need it as an output, I create it in memory.

```
result = processing.runalg('gdalogr:polygonize',layer,"lu_majorit", None)
polygonLayer = processing.getObject(result['OUTPUT'])
```

Then I can use the layer in my file. But I would like to use this layer from another script and I don't succeed.

Here is what I've tried :

in my first script :

```
result = processing.runalg('gdalogr:polygonize',layer,"lu_majorit", None)
polygonLayer = processing.getObject(result['OUTPUT'])
return polygonLayer
```

in my main:

```
polygonLayer=script1(...)
script2(polygonLayer,...)
```

in my second script :

```
cLayer =QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:4326", "OUTPUT", "memory")
```

or:

```
cLayer =QgsVectorLayer("polygonLayer", "OUTPUT", "ogr")
```

Those two ways failed to load the layer.

I tried also by giving the path with :
script 1 :

```
myfilepath= polygonLayer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri()
return myfilepath
```

script2:

```
cLayer =QgsVectorLayer(myfilepath, "OUTPUT", "ogr")
```

This way gives me an invalid syntax.

Does someone know how to do ?

Comment: instead of runalg you can use runandload ( load it to QgsMapLayerRegistry and use it later ) like here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76594/how-to-load-memory-output-from-qgis-processing

Comment: @HichamZouarhi When I replace runalg by runanload I get this message error : "polygonize has no attribute '__getitem__'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both your python files are in the same directory, something like this should work:

## script2

```
def myFunction():
    result = processing.runalg('gdalogr:polygonize',layer,"lu_majorit", None)
    polygonLayer = processing.getObject(result['OUTPUT'])
    return polygonLayer
```

## main script

```
import script2 # for python file named script2.py

polygonLayer = script2.myFunction()
```

If they are not in the same directory you may use the `sys.path.append()` method to append the path of the python script you want to add:

```
sys.path.append('//path/to/other/script/directory')
import script2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My files are in the same directory and I tried this method. But this does not work. It failed to load the layer

Comment: Can you expand more on what you mean by "failed to load the layer"?

Comment: It works !!! I think that I tried too many ways so I mixed up some ... So now that I cleaned my code to explain better my problem, there is no problem anymore. So thank you :)