# Adding temporary output of processing algorithm to the map canvas using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, qgis-processing, memory

Let's say I run a simple algorithm like this

```py
import processing

# https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html?highlight=count%20points%20polygon#id3
processing.run("qgis:countpointsinpolygon", { 
    'POLYGONS' : 'polygons', 
    'POINTS': 'points',
    'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
    })
```

How do I materialize/visualize/add the temporary layer in the Layers Panel?

Comment: Check this tutorial for details: [PyQGIS 101: Running Processing tools](https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis-101-running-processing-tools/)

Comment: Also related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76594/how-to-load-memory-output-from-qgis-processing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another option is `runAndLoadResults()`.

As was mentioned in the [QGIS Documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html#calling-algorithms-from-the-python-console):

> Unlike when an algorithm is executed from the toolbox, outputs are not
> added to the map canvas if you execute that same algorithm from the
> Python console using `run()`, but `runAndLoadResults()` will do that.

```py
processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:countpointsinpolygon", { 
    'POLYGONS' : 'polygons', 
    'POINTS': 'points',
    'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
    })
```

(But I like @MrXsquared option better, since you get the layer as a variable you can then use in the next processing steps).

Comment: your version gives you the layer as a variable, too:
     proc = processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:refactorfields",<<<something>>>)
     outputlayer = proc['OUTPUT']

Answer (score 6):

Can't tell if that is the "best" way, but its one straight forward:

```py
import processing
# https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html?highlight=count%20points%20polygon#id3

proc = processing.run("qgis:countpointsinpolygon", { 
    'POLYGONS' : 'polygons', 
    'POINTS': 'points',
    'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
    })

outputlayer = proc['OUTPUT']
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(outputlayer)
```