# Use raster memory layer from QGIS processing result

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, qgis-processing, memory-layer

I want to apply subsequent QGIS raster processing algorithms in a python script. I want to use memory layers for intermediate calculation results since I am only interested in the end result.

As described in a [previous post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76594/how-to-load-memory-output-from-qgis-processing), for vector layers this works fine when run in the Python console:

```
processing.runandload("qgis:intersection", layer1, layer2, "memory:myLayerName")
```

I can access the "memory:myLayerName" for subsequent calculations.

I'd expect a similar syntax for rasters, but I can't get this (or other functions where a raster is created as an output) to work:

```
processing.runandload("gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer", path_to_raster,
                      path_to_shape, "", False, False, "", "memory:OutputRaster")
```

I get an "Oooops! The following output layers could not be open" - error. The processing.log file shows:

```
'INFO|Sun Mar 01 2015 02:20:52|GDAL execution console output|ERROR 1:
TIFFOpen:memory:temp_layer: Permission denied'
```

When I replace the `"memory:OutputRaster"` with `r"C:/path/to/out/raster.tif"` the code runs. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I can't say exactly why the `runandload` method doesn't work with raster memory layers (not experienced enough) but since you only want to use the result as an intermediate calculation, an alternative can be:

```
int_raster = processing.runalg("gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer", path_to_raster, path_to_shape, "", False, False, "", None)
```

You can use `int_raster` (which is just a name, you can call it whatever you want) as the input for your next process.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I agree, and I would add that one could direct all intermediate results to a temporal directory and, at the end of the process, remove it manually or via the script itself.  That way you can get rid of intermediate results.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph! `intermediate_raster` is a dictionary and `intermediate_raster["OUTPUT"]` returns the path as a string to the output file saved in a temporary folder. Yes, this kind of helps since I don't have to define temporary file paths myself (which I currently do according to @Curlew's comment to [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76166/using-in-memory-vector-layer-with-qgis-processing-sextante)). @gcarrillo, true. But I tried to rather use in-memory layers to avoid attempting to delete physical files which may be locked. Not sure if this is really relevant though.

Comment: Ah well noticed, forgot that `intermediate_raster` was a dictionary! Will edit the post, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a folder in the temporary system as follows:

```
import os, tempfile
tempdir7 = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
```

The path of the temporary folder with the file extension is:

```
rutaProv2=str(tempdir7.name)+'\\x'+str(i)+'.tif'
```

code execution

```
processing.run("gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer", {'INPUT':DTM,'MASK':Shp_Corte,'NODATA':None,'ALPHA_BAND':False,'CROP_TO_CUTLINE':True,'KEEP_RESOLUTION':False,'OPTIONS':'','DATA_TYPE':0,'OUTPUT':rutaProv2}) 
clip_raster = QgsRasterLayer(rutaProv2, 'x'+str(i)+'.tif')
```

Once you finish running your code, you delete the temporary folder.

```
del clip_raster
del tempdir7
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to store rasters layers in memory in QGIS*.

`"memory:abc"` makes QGIS try to write the resulting raster file to the path `memory:abc` and since a `:` character is not allowed in Windows filenames, the error happens.

In modern QGIS you can use `QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT` for the output parameter to make QGIS write a result to a temporary file (in `C:\Temp\` or something similar).

*: Unless you configured your operating system to provide a directory mounted in RAM and tell QGIS to store files there. This is usually the case on Linux.