# Using memory layer as input and/or output with runalg?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

Can a memory layer be used as an input and/or output with *runalg*?

With *runandload* I get this to work:

```
 processing.runandload("qgis:mergevectorlayers","memory:bufferOne", "memory:bufferTwo", r"memory:merged")
 processing.runandload("qgis:dissolve", r"memory:merged", True, '', r"D:\PythonTesting\dissolved.shp")
```

Parameter 2 and 3 are the input layers, which are in memory already, and parameter 3 is the output layer, which is written into memory and used in the following tool (Dissolve). This works fine, but when I try to use the same logic with *runalg*, then my merged layer in memory does not seem to be created, as the Dissolve tool never runs. The following, for example, would not work:

```
 processing.runalg("qgis:mergevectorlayers","memory:bufferOne", "memory:bufferTwo", r"memory:merged")
 processing.runandload("qgis:dissolve", r"memory:merged", True, '', r"D:\PythonTesting\datenschrott\dissolved.shp")
```

Can I assume that *runalg* either does not accept layers that are in memory or that it cannot output any?

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144948/is-it-possible-to-use-memory-layers-in-qgis-processing-algorithms

Answer (score 4):

Not completely sure why your method doesn't work but another method is to instead use `None` when using `runalg` as this will also create an output in memory. Below I defined the first process as `output_0` and called the result of this as input to the second process:

```
output_0 = processing.runalg("qgis:mergevectorlayers",["memory:bufferOne", "memory:bufferTwo"], None)
processing.runandload("qgis:dissolve", output_0['OUTPUT'], True, '', r"D:\PythonTesting\dissolved.shp")
```

Result:

[image: Result]

---

*Tested on QGIS 2.16.0-Nødebo with Processing plugin v2.12.2.*

*Note that* `qgis:mergevectorlayers` *now requires a list of input layers.*

Answer (score 1):

http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/76594/22646 sheds more light on runalg, runandload and memory layer.
According to http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/184802, the way of referring to the resulting memory layer depends on the Processing version.