# QGIS python processing.runalg Clip returns None

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, clip, qgis-processing

I'm writing a script in pyQGIS, which would emulate measurement of a line by "walking" along it with a compass with constant length. I have a problem with the Clip algorythm from processing module, namely it returns None, regardless of whether I add layers as inputs or selected features. What do I do wrong? I believe, that should the clip result in an empty layer, it would still be there, just empty? Below is the piece of code with problems,

```
while d.measureLine(QgsPoint(coorFin[0],coorFin[1]),QgsPoint(coor[0],coor[1]))>step: # If the distance between current and last point is more than chosen step
    # Create buffer polygon around a point
    bufCirc = point.geometry().buffer(step,10) # do a buffer from existing point 
    buforek = QgsFeature()
    buforek.setGeometry(bufCirc)

# Create layer and put the polygon inside
    bufferLayer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon", "temporary_polygons", "memory")
    pz = bufferLayer.dataProvider()
    bufferLayer.setCrs(my_crs)
    pz.addFeatures([buforek])
    bufferLayer.commitChanges()

# select the buffer
    buforSel = bufferLayer.setSelectedFeatures([buforek]) 

# Clip coastline with the buffer
    liniaWarstwa = processing.runandload("qgis:clip", selectedCoastLine, buforSel, "memory:liniaWarstwa")
    print liniaWarstwa
    layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("memory:liniaWarstwa")[0]
```

The print prints "none", QgsMapLayerRegistry says "index out of range".

Comment: Have you tried it without a memory layer? I've had issues recently where memory layers could not be read by processing algorithms. Maybe check with a file on disc, and see if the problem persists or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the newer versions of the *Processing* plugin, it would seem that you can no longer define the name of the output memory layer. The name of the algorithm is used instead (see similar [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184737/using-processing-algorithm-in-qgis-plugin)).

Therefore, you should replace the last section of your code with something similar:

```
# Clip coastline with the buffer
    processing.runandload("qgis:clip", selectedCoastLine, buforSel, None)
    layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("Clipped")[0]
```

Comment: It didn't help, sadly. I updated the plugin, tried what you propose and nothing happened again. I have even tried to use runalg, or output to a location on my hdd, but nothing works. Recently I'm getting "Unable to execute algorithm
Wrong parameter value: Polygon" message, the "polygon" is in constructor of buffer layer (if I change it to e.g. "Polygon?crs=EPSG:xxxx" the word in the message changes accordingly).

Comment: I think when you added your buffer layer, you need to add `bufferLayer.startEditing()` before you can add any features to it.

Comment: Thank you for all answers. I did what you suggested and a few other things (including figuring out, that in Polish version of QGIS the name of output is in Polish...), so I guess I can mark your answer as valid.

Comment: @Julian_P - Glad you got it solved but I would strongly suggest that you post your working solution as an **answer** and accept that. This can help others in a similar situation as you ;)

Answer (score 3):

Aside of what Joseph mentioned, there is a number of other things you need to keep in mind when clipping from/to memory, so a little check-list for all of you using processing algorithms and memory layers:

- check, that your version of processing plugin is the newest (2.12.2 behaves in a way described by Joseph), update if not.
- Make sure all layers are in the same crs, as is your canvas. Have it explicitly set in code.
- Run your desired algorithm from GUI and check what name does an output have. For example Polish version of QGIS has the output names translated, so I had to put "Przycięte" instead of "Clipped"... Alternatively you can change language to English, which may be safer, to avoid specific characters of your language.
- Have both clip layers loaded onto canvas (use QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layerIHoldInMemory) )
- But the most important part of my solution was: Don't use QGIS versions newer than 2.4. It seems, that there is some sort of problem with processing polygons/lines, it works nicely, but on QGIS 2.2 Valmiera.

Comment: It might be really helpful if you post your code as well =)

Comment: I won't because in fact it does work randomly. Sometimes it clips correctly, sometimes it does not even if I don't change a thing in the code. What I listed above is a bunch of advice, a list of factors maybe, but I should add, that it will not result in script doing what you want.

Comment: I understand, that's a fair point :)