# using PyQGIS to subsample a region of a raster layer's pixel data

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-python-console

I am having trouble sampling multiple pixels from a raster layer at oe time. If I want to sample pixel data from a layer at a particular  coordinate I can write.

```
ident = layers[0].dataProvider().identify(QgsPoint(357109.988, 6255412.925),QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue)
```

where my magic numbers come from the x and y coordinates of my CRS for my particular use case; however, I want to sample a rectangular subregion of the layer. looking at the API documentation ( https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterDataProvider.html#a33c343510d534f82c820579b9093fea1 
)it appears that I can do something like this:

```
ident = layers[0].dataProvider().identify(QgsPoint(357109.988, 6255412.925),QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue,QgsRectangle(0,0,2,2),2,2)
```

and that does return a value, but it only returns **one** value. further googling has only turned up the API documentation.

How do I retrieve a nxm array full of band values centered around (or starting from) a point in a raster layer?

Comment: You need a loop for sampling raster values.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround using the `processing.runalg()` method, described in this post: [Using in-memory vector layer with QGIS processing / SEXTANTE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76166/using-in-memory-vector-layer-with-qgis-processing-sextante).

EDIT: the script I copied was for vector clipping (not raster). I replaced it by GDAL's [Clip raster by extent](https://qgis-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_extraction.html) algorithm which does precisely what you want. You need to use the path to your raster as an input (and not the raster itself), though:

```
out_raster = processing.runalg("gdalogr:cliprasterbyextent", "path/to/raster.tif", "", "0,0,2,2", "", None)
```

Answer (score 1):

The API documentation says: "The context parameters theExtent, theWidth and theHeight are important to identify on the same zoom level as a displayed map and to do effective caching (WCS; Web Coverage Service). If context params are not specified the highest resolution is used". Then, I think that it always returns one value. For this reason, if you want to subsample a region of a raster layer's pixel data you can do something as this:

```
mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()

layers = mapcanvas.layers()

extent = layers[1].extent()
xSize = layers[1].rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
ySize = layers[1].rasterUnitsPerPixelY()

rows = layers[1].height()
columns = layers[1].width()

values = [[] for i in range(rows)]

xmin = extent.xMinimum() + xSize/2
ymax = extent.yMaximum() - ySize/2

y = ymax
for i in range(rows):
    x = xmin
    for j in range(columns):
        ident = layers[1].dataProvider().identify(QgsPoint(x, y), QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue)
        values[i].append(ident.results()[1])
        x += xSize
    y -= ySize
```

Above code, it samples all raster layer's pixel data (from red point; see below image) and put them in matrix format (it is very easy to change to array format with 'asarray' numpy method). I tried out with this tif image (20 x 20):

[image]

After running the code at the Python Console of QGIS I got this result:

[image]

where it was corroborated (with value tool plugin) that pixel values were adequately sampled.