# How to select features from one layer and save them to a memory layer?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am new to QGIS Python scripting. I want to select some features from an input layer and save them to a memory layer for further processing. Here is my code:

```
##Sampled_trees=vector
##Input_field= field Sampled_trees

from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

inputTrees= processing.getObject(Sampled_trees)
inputField = inputTrees.fieldNameIndex(Input_field)

tempLayer = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "temporary_points", "memory")

processing.runalg("qgis:selectbyattribute", inputTrees, inputField,0,1,inputTrees)
processing.runalg('qgis:saveselectedfeatures', inputTrees, tempLayer)
```

When the last line is executed, I get the error:

> TypeError: 
>   'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I think this question may be a duplicate of this one: [Using in-memory vector layer with QGIS processing / SEXTANTE](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76166/using-in-memory-vector-layer-with-qgis-processing-sextante)

Comment: It is a similar question. I studied that question before asking this one but that answer was not useful for me. So I had to ask again and I got the answer I needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you noted in your question you may also use memory layer to add selected features from source layer, see code below:

```
inputTrees= processing.getObject(Sampled_trees)
inputField = inputTrees.fieldNameIndex(Input_field)
processing.runalg("qgis:selectbyattribute", inputTrees, Input_field, 0, 1)
tempLayer = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "temporary_points", "memory")
features = inputTrees.selectedFeatures()
temp_data = tempLayer.dataProvider()
attr = inputTrees.dataProvider().fields().toList()
temp_data.addAttributes(attr)
tempLayer.updateFields()
temp_data.addFeatures(features)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(tempLayer)
```

Comment: This is what I needed. It is working and really useful!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `None` as the output which automatically creates a temporary layer. This is mentioned in the [documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html#calling-algorithms-from-the-python-console):

> For output data objects, type the file path to be used to save it, just as it is done from the toolbox. If you want to save the result to a temporary file, use `None`.

So your code can be shortened to:

```
##Sampled_trees=vector
##Input_field= field Sampled_trees

inputTrees= processing.getObject(Sampled_trees)
inputField = inputTrees.fieldNameIndex(Input_field)

processing.runalg("qgis:selectbyattribute", inputTrees, Input_field, 0, 1)
tempLayer = processing.runalg('qgis:saveselectedfeatures', inputTrees, None)
```

---

*Note that for the `qgis:selectbyattribute` algorithm, you don't specify the output as you are only selecting features from the input layer.*

Comment: Using None argument for qgis:saveselectedfeatures saves the layer to disk, e.g. C:\\Users\\userName\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\processing68ace1dd77264cf48d1f95eb837b93d1\\86ee4684d3784c7eb27506235b395999\\OUTPUTLAYER.shp, I'm not sure this is a temporary layer.

Comment: Yes, the result of 
    processing.runalg('qgis:saveselectedfeatures', inputTrees, None)
was a python dictionary containing the name of the output layer and the path to that layer. That file can be imported as a temporary layer.

Comment: @artwork21 - My understanding is that a **temporary** layer is that which is saved to disk temporarily until it is deleted either by restarting the computer or any other means; a **memory** layer is that which is stored in the memory used by QGIS and is deleted when QGIS is closed. I guess both layers are _temporary_ but I'll edit the title to reflect that a memory layer was needed =)

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now I can understand the difference between the two concepts.