# Use temporary vector layer in scripts

Tags: pyqgis, vector

I would like to create a vector layer, add a point to it and then use it in qgis algorithms.

This is what I wrote :

```
#create temporary layer containing center point
    point=QgsFeature()
    point.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(center[0],center[1])))
    pointlayer=QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=epsg:2154", "temporary_points", "memory")
    pointlayer.startEditing()
    pointlayer.addFeatures([point])
    pointlayer.commitChanges()

    #intersection between point layer and polygon layers to get names codes
    fieldname_vector=processing.runalg('qgis:intersection', parcel, pointlayer, False, None)
```

But when the algorithm runs, it returns

```
    Unable to execute algorithm
Wrong parameter value: Point?crs=epsg:2154
```

Is there a way to use my layer without saving it, knowing that I'll erase it in the future ?

Comment: Ok thanks, do you know why it's impossible to use it without adding it to the layer's panel ?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, you can load it in the _Layers Panel_ without it being shown. A related question regarding this was asked before: [Using in-memory vector layer with QGIS processing / SEXTANTE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76166/using-in-memory-vector-layer-with-qgis-processing-sextante).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the memory layer to the QgsMapLayerRegistry **before** you can use it in processing. But you can add it without it being shown in the *Layers Panel* by using:

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(pointlayer, False)
```

When finished, you can then do some cleanup by removing and deleting it:

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(pointlayer)
del pointlayer
```

Comment: In QGIS 3 the QgsMapLayerRegistry has been removed but the layer can be added via `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(pointlayer, False)`.

Comment: @Orienteerix - Thanks for the extra info :)